# exception when adding the onclick to a td on asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have this asp.net code

```
<asp:TableCell CssClass="plusTd button" ID="plusCell">
                        </asp:TableCell>
```

I need when i click to that `td`, I want to open a page.

I tried this:

```
plusCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "/Add.aspx");
```

but when i click on that `td`, Chrome F12 console shows me this exception:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
```

and the html code that has the error is:

```
<td id="plusCell" class="plusTd button" onclick="/Add.aspx"></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 plusCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "onClickTd()");
```

and add this js function.

```
function onClickTd
{
   window.location.assign('/Add.aspx');
}
```